# How to check if the user has the library in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, shared-libraries

For example, if I developed a c++ project and put it on GitHub as a open source project. In my project I used *log4cpp* as a 3rd-party library to do log stuff. Interested users would download my project and run "make" and suddenly found their machines just don't recognize log4cpp.

I need you guys to verify my original thoughts:

Unlike Java which you may simply include the 3rd-party jar file in your package, I know that C++ is kind of different: you have to let the client compile the library by themselves. It is obvious that, if I do not have the source code from the 3rd-party, I simply cannot *help* the client to install the libraries. Instead, I need to check if the user has already installed those required library and if not, just warn them not proceed.

If these statements were true, what tools should I consider to use to check? Also, an add-on question: if I want to produce a non-open source product, what should I do? (Since the client need my source code to compile.) If not(Especially the *compile by themselves* part), please give me your explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: The straight forward way is just relying on installation and add a `-l<libname>` option to your linker command line. Checks can be done beforehand though.

Comment: I still need to copy all 3rd party header files in my `include` folders, right?

Comment: No you don't need to copy anything. If these are installed correctly, they' ll appear in `/usr/include` or so. Otherwise use the `-L` `-I` options to specify paths where these files should be found.

Comment: You could look into the [`autoconf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html) ecosystem so that people run a configure script which analyzes where software is installed and ensures that the `makefile` is told where to find the headers and libraries.  If the software should be, and normally is, installed in `/usr/lib` and /`usr/include`, you might get away without, but if some people install in `/usr/local` and others in `/opt/package` and so on, then you may be better off with such a configuration system.

Comment: additional to autoconf, cmake is also popular for checking dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Example makefile:

```
ifeq "$(shell echo '\#include <readline/readline.h>\nint main(){return 0;}' | $(CC) -x c -Wall -O -o /dev/null > /dev/null 2> /dev/null - && echo $$? )" "0"
  HAS_FILE = yes
else
  HAS_FILE = no
endif

all:
  echo has_file=$(HAS_FILE)
```

I will not say that this is a recommended method, I just use it for simple checks. Autoconf may be a better option.